# Binary Distance between the two Primes

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, prime-numbers

Given a prime number `p`, is there always a smaller positive integer exponent `k` such that `p+2^k` is also prime? We will call the smallest possible value of this exponent the k*.
We could interpret this number `k` as the position where we could add 1 to the binary expression of `p` in order to obtain another prime number, the smallest possible one.

For example, `61+2^8 = 317`. The prime number 61 has a binary expression of 111101 and its "binary distance" function is equal to `8 (dyb[61]=8)`. This means that in the 8th position of its binary expression, we need to add a 1 (considering the first position as 0, so we have positions from 0 to 5 in 111101): 100111101, which is equal to the prime number 317.
`31+2^4 = 47 dyb[31]=4`, since 31 in base 2 is 11111, and 47 in base 2 is 101111.

I made the following implementation:

```
dyb[n_] := Module[{c = 0, p = 0, i = 1},
  If[n > 2 && PrimeQ[n],
    While[! PrimeQ[n + 2^i], i = i + 1; p = i; c = p; ]; c ]]

Print[dyb[61]]
```

I would like to obtain a table with a certain quantity of primes, with the first column containing the primes `p`, the second column containing the binary distance `k`, and the third column containing the second prime `q`.

```
Prime p ----- Binary distance ----- Prime q
  61             8                   317
```

Comment: seems like there is a typo at the end of the sentence... We will call the smallest possible value of this exponent the " . perhaps we can call this k* ? please change the edit if this makes no sense

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like `Grid[Table[p = Prime[n]; {p, dyb[p], p + 2^dyb[p]}, {n, 1, 10}],  Frame -> All]`?

EDIT:
I think this fixes your function:

```
dyb[n_] := Module[{i = 0}, If[PrimeQ[n], While[! PrimeQ[n + 2^i], i = i + 1;]; i]];
Grid[Table[p = Prime[n]; {p, dyb[p], p + 2^dyb[p]}, {n, 2, 20}], Frame -> All]
```

Comment: It seems that your function `dyp`is not working correctly for all prime numbers, or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: In fact. His table demonstrated some primes where it doesn't work. The table should provide                                                                                                                           p   dist q
2 0 3
3 1 5
5 1 7
7 2 11
11 1 13
13 2 17
17 1 19
19 2 23
23 3 31
29 1 31
31 4 47
37 2 41

Comment: @RubensVilhenaFonseca I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
dyb[n_] := Module[{i = 0}, If[n > 2 && PrimeQ[n], While[! PrimeQ[n + 2^i], i = i + 1;]; i]]

primes = Select[Range[2, 97], PrimeQ];

resp = Table[dyb[n], {n, primes}];

Grid[Transpose[{primes, resp}], Dividers -> {{2 -> True}, {2 -> True}}, 
    Alignment -> {{Center, Center}}, BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", 
    FontSize -> 14}, FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.005], 
    GrayLevel[0.7]], Background -> {{GrayLevel[0.95], {LightGray, GrayLevel[0.92]}}}]
```

Comment: Your answer would be better, if you used the code to generate some numerical values.